# Protractor - jasmine; How to click submit button

Tags: automated-testing, protractor

Our dev has a submit button like this:

```
<button _ngcontent-c6="" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg" type="submit">Login</button>
```

I tried using:

```
element(by.buttonText('#submit'));
```

but no luck with it.

Note: I'm new to protractor.

Comment: In `buttonText` locator, you give the text of button, not the id. Try using `by.buttonText('Login')`

Comment: element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();

Answer (score 1):

Use the following cssSelector:

```
var loginBtn = element(by.css(button[type = 'submit']));
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `by.css("button[type = 'submit']")` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is mismatch. You are trying to use ID as text which is incorrect.

If you want to use `by.buttonText` then your code should be `by.buttonText('Login')`

Or you can also use css selector like `element(by.css(button[type = 'submit']));`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use submit property in this scenario instead of button text as it is less fragile *as it is less likely to be changed* compared to  text.

I would use precisely:

```
$('button[type="submit"]')
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why your code would be better than the other answers.

Comment: @Kate, edited the answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
element(by.xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Login")]')).click();
```